# Selecting max(date) from union query

Tags: mysql, union

I am having a bit of trouble getting accurate results from a query that looks to me as if it should work. RDBMS is MySQL.

I am trying to get the max last login date from a union select on three databases for Atlassian products JIRA, Confluence and Stash. There should only be a single entry in the results for each user (the max(Last_Login) is supposed to get the maximum last login date and show a result if that max(Last_Login) is older than today - 90 days.

I summarize the output of the union query then select from that aggregate so that I can get the max login date that is 90 days ago or prior.

**The problem:** The query seems to work for the most part, but there are a handful of cases where a user shows activity in Confluence, Stash or JIRA interfaces that is more recent than what I have here.

Here is the query I am attempting to use:

```
select
    User_Name,
    First_Name,
    Last_Name,
    max(Last_Login) as Last_Login
FROM
(
SELECT
    u.user_name as User_Name,
    u.first_name as First_Name,
    u.last_name Last_Name,
    ifnull(from_unixtime((cast(a.attribute_value AS UNSIGNED)/1000), '%Y-%m-%d'), '1970-01-01') AS Last_Login
FROM jira.cwd_user u
  LEFT JOIN jira.cwd_user_attributes a ON u.id = a.user_id AND a.attribute_name = 'login.lastLoginMillis'
  JOIN jira.cwd_directory d ON u.directory_id = d.id
where u.active = 1
UNION
select
    u.user_name as User_Name,
    u.first_name as First_Name,
    u.last_name Last_Name, 
    ifnull(from_unixtime((cast(ca.attribute_value AS UNSIGNED)/1000), '%Y-%m-%d'), '1970-01-01') AS Last_Login
FROM confluence.cwd_user u
  LEFT JOIN confluence.cwd_user_attribute ca ON u.id = ca.user_id AND ca.attribute_name = 'login.lastLoginMillis'
  JOIN confluence.cwd_directory d ON u.directory_id = d.id
where u.active = 'T'
UNION
select
    u.user_name as User_Name,
    u.first_name as First_Name,
    u.last_name Last_Name,
    ifnull(from_unixtime((cast(sa.attribute_value AS UNSIGNED)/1000), '%Y-%m-%d'), '1970-01-01') AS Last_Login
FROM stash.cwd_user u
LEFT JOIN stash.cwd_user_attribute sa ON u.id = sa.user_id AND sa.attribute_name = 'login.lastLoginMillis'
JOIN stash.cwd_directory d ON u.directory_id = d.id
where u.is_active = 'T'
) as z
group by User_Name, First_Name, Last_Name
having (max(Last_Login)) <= date_sub(now(), interval 90 day)
order by User_Name asc, Last_Login desc
```

Comment: Can you give us sample rows for the user that has newer than 90 days activity and does not appear in the result?

Comment: @ypercube: the user shows in the result, but his last login date shows as '1970-01-01'

Comment: Show us the related rows from the tables (confluence.cwd_user, confluence.cwd_user_attribute, confluence.cwd_directory).

Comment: @ypercube: So there was a mistake in the query and the confluence query was returning 0 results with u.active = 1. It is stored as "T" or "F" in that database. I changed the query to reflect this and it is tested returning 913 rows now, but the two users who have logged in are still showing last_login of '1970-01-01'. Unfortunately, I can't show the rows themselves because of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that confluence uses a different structure to manage this data and now the discrepancies appear to be resolved.

Here is the query:

```
select
    User_Name,
    First_Name,
    Last_Name,
    max(Last_Login) as Last_Login
FROM
(
SELECT
    u.user_name as User_Name,
    u.first_name as First_Name,
    u.last_name Last_Name,
    ifnull(from_unixtime((cast(a.attribute_value AS UNSIGNED)/1000), '%Y-%m-%d'), '1970-01-01') AS Last_Login
FROM jira.cwd_user u
  LEFT JOIN jira.cwd_user_attributes a ON u.id = a.user_id AND a.attribute_name = 'login.lastLoginMillis'
  JOIN jira.cwd_directory d ON u.directory_id = d.id
where u.active = 1
UNION
 SELECT 
    u.user_name, 
    u.first_name as First_Name, 
    u.last_name as Last_Name, 
    date_format(l.successdate, '%Y-%m-%d') as Last_Login 
  FROM confluence.logininfo l 
  JOIN confluence.user_mapping m ON m.user_key = l.username 
  JOIN confluence.cwd_user u ON m.username = u.user_name 
  JOIN confluence.cwd_directory d ON u.directory_id = d.id and u.active = 'T' 
UNION
select
    u.user_name as User_Name,
    u.first_name as First_Name,
    u.last_name Last_Name,
    ifnull(from_unixtime((cast(sa.attribute_value AS UNSIGNED)/1000), '%Y-%m-%d'), '1970-01-01') AS Last_Login
FROM stash.cwd_user u
LEFT JOIN stash.cwd_user_attribute sa ON u.id = sa.user_id AND sa.attribute_name = 'login.lastLoginMillis'
JOIN stash.cwd_directory d ON u.directory_id = d.id
where u.is_active = 'T'
) as z
group by User_Name, First_Name, Last_Name
having (max(Last_Login)) <= date_sub(now(), interval 90 day)
order by User_Name asc, Last_Login desc
```